# org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter was found, but is missing another required class

Tags: struts2

So, this is my current configuration:

- Dynamic Web Project (not maven)
- Java 8
- Tomcat 9
- Struts 2.5

UI can display and work in Tomcat Server, but having the error message below when EAR package is deployed to WAS.

> Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [struts2]:
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter was
> found, but is missing another required class.

Here's my added jar files:
[JAR files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tPWE.png)

Comment: Consider not doing library management by hand. You can use Maven to determine the runtime library dependencies if you're insistent on doing the packaging yourself, though.

Comment: Nothing is expected to work with misconfigured application server or your application. Without details is impossible to diagnose the problem. From the message above you can evolve that you have the problem with starting a Struts2 filter. That's it.